# Baer sum and endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I work in an Abelian category. If I take the Baer sum of two extensions $M'$ and $M''$ of $
M_2$ by $M_1$, i.e.,
$$ 0 \to M_1 \to M' \to M_2 \to 0$$
is exact, and the same for $M''$, then what do I know about $\mathrm{End}(M' + M'')$? Do I have any access to it? I know everything I want about the other objects (I know $\mathrm{End}(M')$, $\mathrm{End}(M'')$, $\mathrm{End}(M_1)$ and $\mathrm{End}(M_2)$, and also all of their $\mathrm{Hom}$ sets, for instance). I use the definition of Baer sum as successive pullback and pushout of $M' \oplus M''$ by the diagonal and codiagonal maps on $M_2$ and $M_1$, so a more general (and maybe easier) question is: what do I know about the endomorphism ring of the pullback / pushout of two objects, if I know the objects?

I posted the same question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356899/baer-sum-and-endomorphisms).